# Should I install some OS on Dell EqualLogic PS4100 array to use it as storage only?

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge, dell-equallogic

I have Dell PowerEdge Server R710 on which I installed ESXi. I also have a storage array, Dell EqulLogic PS4100. I would like to use my array as the storage only, I mean, using ESXi with vCenter Client I would like to create some virtual machines on my storage.

My question is: should I install some OS on my Dell EqualLogic? Or I can simply treat it as a regular HDD, and create VMFS on it? Im a little bit confused with all this, please, help.

Does EqualLogic need some setup and configuration or can I just use it out of the box? How can I configure EqalLogic IP addres in order to be able to use it via the net?

Comment: You need to hire someone with storage experience. ASAP. How do you even get a $10k piece of hardware like your PS4100 without knowing the basic fundamentals of hashtag you've purchased? Download the manual and read it at a bare minimum before you do something crazy.

Comment: You should speak to someone about getting some education in respect of the tools you are trying to use - you desperately need it.

Comment: Side note: somehow "what" was autocorrected to "hashtag" and I didn't catch it until the edit window passed...so that's cool.

Comment: I would be carefull about 10k USD ;) I checked dell and do not find a 4100 - just followup models. That may be a MUCH cheaper "one or two generations out" models puchased on ebay ;) Not a bad avenue, but puts the money into relations.

Answer (score 6):

Do you know sherlock holmes? Read them. One lesson: Eliminate the impossible, then the rest makes sense.

> My question is: should I install some OS on my Dell EqualLogic?

And what exactly do you think you would install on hardware that has firmware that is a dedicated storage array, as also said in the documentation.

Accoring to Dell it is a storage array. Not a normal computer. You also do not get the idea of installing a operating system on your cisco routers, or?

> Does EqualLogic need some setup and configuration or can I just use it out of the box?

Read the documentation first. Helps tons - and makes sure we professionals do not close questions as "lacking basic understanding of the technologies involved".